# Getting data from different folders

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two sets of json files store in two folders(named firstdata and seconddata) separately. I am trying to read all files in that two folders and put it into two arrays separately. Here is the code I did:

```
directory = os.path.normpath("D:\Python\project")
for subdir, dir, file in os.walk(directory):
    if subdir == 'D:\Python\project\firstdata':
        for f in file:
            if f.endswith(".json"):
                fread=open(os.path.join(subdir, f),'r')
                a = fread.next().replace('\n','').split(',')

                for line in a:
                    b = line.replace('.','').replace('\n','').replace('"','').split(': ')

            print "___________________________________________________________________"
            fread.close()
```

However it ignores (if subdir == 'D:\Python\project\firstdata': ) and get nothing at the end, can anyone helps?

Comment: use `print(subdir)` to see what you get. Besides char \ has special meaning in text like "\n" or "\t" so better in path use \\ or / (`D:\\Python` or `D:/Python`)

Comment: Thank you! it works after I use \\ . In fact, I did try print (subdir) but it showed me D:\Python\project\firstdata on cmd, so I used that but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are interpreting things wrong. See the docs for [`**os.walk**`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk).

The 3 variables for your `for` loop should be `root`, `dirs`, and `files`, in that order.

`dirs` and `files` are lists, of the directories and files in the current directory respectively. `root` is the current directory you are in.

`subdir` is being ignored because you are using `os.walk` incorrectly.